# Cutting string by pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have large string in SQL Server table.

Example one record table row:

```
06.10.2013 22:49:25 [Server Name] INFO - received /192.168.77.14:45643 User-Name: Jon Johnson still something between Client IP: 172.29.5.43
```

But I need just:

```
06.10.2013 22:49:25 User-Name: Jon Johnson Client IP: 172.29.5.43
```

How can I do it? I tried with PATINDEX but :\

Comment: Combination of `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING` calls that will require a bit of tweaking to make it right. What's your rules when the each part begins or ends? Specially on that "still something between" after username - how do you know username ended and something else begun?

Comment: I say if you know RegEx you can use that even,

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
LEFT(c, 19) -- fixed length for date-time
+ ' ' -- separator
-- now let's find the user-name.
+ SUBSTRING(c, CHARINDEX('User-Name:',c), CHARINDEX(' still something',c ) - CHARINDEX('User-Name:',c)) -- 'User-name:' string must be present only once in the row-column. Replace ' still something' string with the actual content. You use it to delimit the username itself.
+ ' ' -- separator
+ SUBSTRING(c, CHARINDEX('Client IP:',c) /* first character position to include */, LEN(c) - CHARINDEX('Client IP:',c) + 1 /* last character position not to include */) -- 'Client IP:' string must be resent only once in the row-column. Expects the IP to be the last part of the string, otherwise use the technique from the username

-- now the dummy table for the testing
FROM 
(SELECT '06.10.2013 22:49:25 [Server Name] INFO - received /192.168.77.14:45643 User-Name: Jon Johnson still something between Client IP: 172.29.5.43' AS c) AS t
```

Answer (score 0):

If your string is well formed (you always find tokens Server Name and User Name) you can apply with PATINDEX to get the index you want and then apply a SUBSTIRNG like this:

Show [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14569/11/0)

```
select
substring(description, 1, patindex('%Server Name%', description) - 3) +
substring(description, patindex('%User-name%', description) + 9, 500)
from myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

The date part of column is fixed so fixed length can be extracted using `SUBSTRING` function.

Complete query is:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(fieldname,1,20) + SUBSTRING(fieldname, CHARINDEX('User-Name', 

fieldname), LENGTH(fieldname)-CHARINDEX('User-Name', fieldname)) from table;
```

Comment: `INSTR` and `CONCAT` do not exist in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that might work, but you really need to replace that 'still something between' with something more solid:

```
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @s = '06.10.2013 22:49:25 [Server Name] INFO - received /192.168.77.14:45643 User-Name: Jon Johnson still something between Client IP: 172.29.5.43'


SELECT SUBSTRING(@s,0,CHARINDEX('[Server Name]',@s)) --everything up to [Server Name]
   + SUBSTRING(@s, CHARINDEX('User-Name',@s),CHARINDEX('still something between', @s)-CHARINDEX('User-Name',@s)) --everything from User-Name to 'still something between'
   + SUBSTRING(@s, CHARINDEX('Client IP',@s),LEN(@s)) --from Client IP till the end
```